# Odd code added just before close body tag

Tags: php, html

My client is reporting that code looking like this has been automatically added to the end of all PHP files (just before the close body tag):

```
<b1><!--J5qN2aS2eNoNycENgCAMAMCNqEoUnYZA04DRUgI1rC+f+xxwUdDQEuliwe5u3U+wzm3HBWMMkxpR0Qnmr2E2KAyDIqAUnQGM3H0NiXwUed67q6m5/t4jHpA=--></b1>
```

He tried manually deleting that line, but of course it reappears. Googleing returns very little:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?t=652089

Can anyone help point us in the right direction? Anything particular to look for?

Comment: Are you using a php framework or pre-packaged cms?

Comment: The CMS is our custom built product. It powers hundreds of sites, but none report this problem. This particular site also happens to be hosted externally (we offer hosting at Rackspace, but they're not using it).

Comment: Is that line in the actual PHP source files or just in the output?

Comment: It's in the actual template files themselves, not just when viewing source from a browser.

Comment: who is hosting your php file?  could be your host doing something stupid.

Comment: You might want to also check your .htaccess file(s) and make sure no weird pre processing is happening.

Comment: Perhaps you could post what CMS you use? Or something else? This alone isn't enough to diagnose or solve your problem.

Comment: He contacted his host: "they believe there could be a file or exploit within the site files with a "entry point". I haven't been able to find any files that look out of the ordinary.

The CMS is MonkCMS, which, as I mentioned, is custom built by us. .htaccess also looks normal.

Honestly, my hope was that someone would see that example, and immediately recognize it. I find it very peculiar that I can't find more information via google.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a encrypted base 64 encoded string.

```
J5qN2aS2eNoNycENgCAMAMCNqEoUnYZA04DRUgI1rC+f+xxwUdDQEuliwe5u3U+wzm3HBWMMkxpR0Qnmr2E2KAyDIqAUnQGM3H0NiXwUed67q6m5/t4jHpA=
```

Decoding doesn't seem to provide any useful information. **I would assume the host is compromised.**

One of my clients had a similar problem on one of his websites: turns out there was an upload form that didn't had proper file validation, a Perl script was uploaded and executed via the web server and gave the attacker almost root access to the server by creating a deamon.

Comment: It is possible that something like that is what happened. I believe they have a few custom forms on the site. Where would you suggest checking to see evidence of this, and potentially remove it? Will there be a tell-tale file, or is this all going to be happening in memory?

Comment: I lost my giant comment so I'm gonna be brief. You might have a better luck posting this @ ServerFault and asking your sysadmin / host provider what happened. In my case all the log files (all the files starting with "log*" actually) disappeared, so I made a diff between the files and the backup and some addicional files came up, among those was the rootkit.

Answer (score 0):

change FTP password. maybe it was stole from total commander or other FTP client by some trojan.

there was a similar problem with bunch `iframe`s added to the code before the closing tag. password change is the only thing that helps.

Comment: Changing the password didn't help me a bit. I also had to remove the rootkit.

Comment: Client *did* change the FTP password, but that did not help.